# How do you make 3 rows and 3 columns fill the screen?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4, and I have 3 rows and 3 columns that are images. The images are 670px x 670px.  Currently they fit the width fine but only The first row and a half are visible.  I'd like all rows and columns to be visible on page load.  Is there a way of making them fit the height and width?

I've tried 100vh on the parent container but to no avail...

https://codepen.io/samgardiner/pen/XLLePR

```
<section class="work-hub">
        <div class="container-fluid h-100">
            <div class="work-hub__row row">
                <div class="work-hub__col col-sm-4 p-0">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/670" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="work-hub__col col-sm-4 p-0">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/670" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="work-hub__col col-sm-4 p-0">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/670" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="work-hub__row row">
                <div class="work-hub__col col-sm-4 p-0">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/670" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="work-hub__col col-sm-4 p-0">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/670" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="work-hub__col col-sm-4 p-0">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/670" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="work-hub__row row">
                <div class="work-hub__col col-sm-4 p-0">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/670" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="work-hub__col col-sm-4 p-0">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/670" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="work-hub__col col-sm-4 p-0">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/670" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

it should work with these CSS rules :

```
.work-hub__col {
  height: calc(100vh / 3 );
}

.work-hub__col > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZddapX

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks very much!